# Linked list и работа с объектом

Tags: java, list, коллекции, linked-list

Видел что именно так надо объявлять и так правильней.

```
 List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

Но когда через объект вызываю метод: `addFirst()`, то идея сама подставляет вот такую конструкцию:

```
((LinkedList<String>) list).addFirst();
```

Почему я просто не могу сделать `list.addFirst()` подскажите пожалуйста!
Заметил что работает только если объявить вот так:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

Но как я уже показывал выше правильней использовать вот такую конструкцию:

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

Поправьте если ошибаюсь

Comment: да потому что у интерфейса `List` нет метода `addFirst` у него просто метод `add`. Ну и собственно если вам уметь добавлять в начало то пишите `LinkedList<String> list` ничего в этом плохого нет. Ну и `Deque` посмотреть

Comment: @pavel это понятно. Просто что тогда использовать первую конструкцию с интерфейсом List или LinkedList, не в данном случаи, а вообще.

Comment: если речь про _вообще_, то использовать нужно самый верхний из классов иерархии в котором есть весь необходимый набор методов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

`Deque<String> list = new LinkedList<>();`

---

Нужно использовать родителя самого высокого уровня, функциональности которого достаточно для решения задачи. Особенно это важно при создании библиотеки.

Т.е. вы думаете "а что мне вообще нужно от этого объекта", исходя из этого уже и принимаете решение. Например `Map<K,V>` при использовании почти всегда всё равно `HashMap TreeMap` или иное. Поэтому пишем `Map`.

В данном примере из класса `LinkedList` используется метод `addFirst` который был получен из интерфейса `Deque`. Если вы хотите использовать именно его (не `add(int index, E element)`) то пишите `Deque` если для вас критичен произвольный доступ (по фрагменту кода это непонятно), то пишите `LinkedList`

Comment: Но LinkedList наследуется от List и от Deque, но List получается родитель самого высокого уровня  получается?

Comment: Так для обычного примера понятно, что можно Deque или просто LinkedList<> list. А вот для Arraylist(a) обычная такая конструкция List<> list = ArrayList<>(); почему так же для LinkedList(a) не делают?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван да он много от чего наследуется. Вплоть до `Iterable` Только вот в `List` нет такого метода который вы используете.

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван делают. Когда например `removeRange` нужен или подобное. В общем когда интерфейса не хватает надо спускаться ниже.

Comment: А всё понял, теперь осталось узнать как спускаться ниже чтобы ничего не сломать что было выше))

Comment: не сломаете) если оно работает с родителем, то должно работать и с любым наследником (буква L из SOLID).